# How to select results with and without a condition?

Tags: sql, sqlite, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have several queries where I need to do one query with a condition, and another one without the condition (typically to calculate a ratio of `<results with condition>/<all results>`):

```sql
-- all results
select count(*)
from somewhere

-- filtered results
select count(*)
from somewhere
where condition
```

The actual query is much longer with several joins and I would ideally love to have one that would encompass both cases.  Is this possible?

Comment: What does it mean to have "one that would encompass both cases"?

Comment: @ScottHunter: I mean to get both counts in one SQL request (instead of two)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing conditional aggregation. Your pseudo-code would look like:

```
select count(*) as total,
    sum(case when <condition> then 1   else 0 end) as total_with_cond,
    avg(case when <condition> then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_with_cond
from somewhere
```

Where `<condition>` represents the predicate you want to check on each row.

In SQLite, that can evaluate predicate in numeric context, we can further shorten the syntax like so:

```
select count(*) as total,
    sum(<condition>) as total_with_cond,
    avg(<condition>) as ratio_with_cond
from somewhere
```

Answer (score 1):

A simplification of the exact two pseudo queries you gave above might be:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) AS ratio
FROM somewhere;
```

Here we are using conditional aggregation to find the count with a condition.  Note that the above query only has to make a single pass over your table and so is efficient.